# How to set the color of the background tabitem that is select, WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, vb.net, visual-studio, tabcontrol

How to set the color of the background tabitem that is select?
The color of the text changes, the background does not:

```
Sub changebackgroundcolorwhenselected(ByVal tabitem1 As TabItem)
    tabitem1.Background = Brushes.DeepSkyBlue
    tabitem1.Header = "House"
    Dim tr As New Trigger()
    tr.Property = TabItem.IsSelectedProperty
    tr.Value = True
    Dim h As New Setter(TabItem.BackgroundProperty, Brushes.Red) '?
    tr.Setters.Add(h)
    Dim h2 As New Setter(TabItem.ForegroundProperty, Brushes.Green)
    tr.Setters.Add(h2)
    Dim x As New Style
    x.Triggers.Add(tr)
    tabitem1.Style = x
End Sub
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [WPF: How to set background of TabItem?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6273847/wpf-how-to-set-background-of-tabitem)

Comment: No, just no code. Need help, not blame.

Comment: Have you read this post linked from that? The sample code specifies green for selected tabitem and red for the others. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3265140/wpf-tabitem-background-color-changes-when-tabitem-selected-or-hover-over

Comment: needed not xaml

Comment: You cannot use XAML at all? How about define the style in XAML and apply it from VB code? If no, you need to build the `ControlTemplate` dynamically on your VB code according to that sample XAML.