# How to disable the WPF tabItem Background when mouseOver

Tags: c#, wpf, background, mouseevent, tabitem

I already set the `Background` and the `Border` of the `TabItem` to `Transparent`. However, when my mouse is over the `TabItem`, the `Background` of the `TabItem`will turn to grey color. Does anyone how to disable the `Background` when the tabitems are being mouse over? I found a link [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3265140/wpf-tabitem-background-color-changes-when-tabitem-selected-or-hover-over), but it doesn't work for me.

Image before mouse over:

[image]

Image after mouse over:

[image]

Comment: Have you tried the solution in the link you posted with a trigger on  `IsMouseOver`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have full control over control appearance by customize its style. If you have Expression blend, it will be easier. Here's a very nice [tutorial](http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/the-wpf-tab-control-inside-and-out)