# How to Change the Background of certain tabs?

Tags: c#, wpf

So I have a tabcontrol with several tabitems. I want to include this function such that whenever I right-click on a tab (currently selected or not), that tab's color will be changed. If I do that again, the color is back to default (the grayish color).

How do I do that? Should I have two sets of tab looks and have them as dynamic resources and have a listener that would change them on the fly?

Any help or pointing me to the right direction is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

ps. I'm developing a WPF application and following MVVM.

Comment: Have a bool property for tabrightselected, toggle this on tab right click and create style setters which depend on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The same kind of problem already discussed and solution had been given. [Refer this url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3265140/wpf-tabitem-background-color-changes-when-tabitem-selected-or-hover-over])

Answer (score 0):

Try it out this another solution,

```
public class MyTabItem : TabItem
    {

        protected override void OnMouseRightButtonDown(MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            this.Background = Brushes.Yellow;
            base.OnMouseRightButtonDown(e);
        }       
    }
```

Just override the Tabitem and change the color whenever you required