# How to add IsPressed state in TabItem in WPF XAML

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml

I am using TabItem in WPF window and wants to change to background of TabItem when user pressed it.

How to do it in XAML?

Comment: Please refer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3265140/wpf-tabitem-background-color-changes-when-tabitem-selected-or-hover-over

Comment: The above link is for selected tab not for pressed tab

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all you need create your own TabItem.

```
public class MyTabItem : TabItem
{
    public bool IsPressed
    {
        get { return (bool)GetValue(IsPressedProperty); }
        set
        {
            SetValue(IsPressedProperty, value);
        }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty IsPressedProperty =
       DependencyProperty.Register("IsPressed", typeof(bool), typeof(MyTabItem), new PropertyMetadata(false));

    protected override void OnMouseDown(MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnMouseDown(e);
        IsPressed = true;
    }

    protected override void OnMouseLeave(MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnMouseLeave(e);
        IsPressed = false;
    }

    protected override void OnMouseUp(MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnMouseUp(e);
        IsPressed = false;
    }
}
```

Then create Style in XAML for your new control with custom ControlTemplate and Trigger for IsPressed property

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type local:MyTabItem}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:MyTabItem}">
                <Grid SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                    <Border x:Name="Bd" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="1,1,1,0" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}">
                        <ContentPresenter x:Name="Content" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding HeaderTemplate}" Content="{TemplateBinding Header}" ContentStringFormat="{TemplateBinding HeaderStringFormat}" ContentSource="Header" HorizontalAlignment="{Binding HorizontalContentAlignment, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorLevel=1, AncestorType={x:Type ItemsControl}}}" RecognizesAccessKey="True" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" VerticalAlignment="{Binding VerticalContentAlignment, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorLevel=1, AncestorType={x:Type ItemsControl}}}"/>
                    </Border>
                </Grid>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="Bd">
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0,1" StartPoint="0,0">
                                    <GradientStop Color="#FFEAF6FD" Offset="0.15"/>
                                    <GradientStop Color="#FFD9F0FC" Offset="0.5"/>
                                    <GradientStop Color="#FFBEE6FD" Offset="0.5"/>
                                    <GradientStop Color="#FFA7D9F5" Offset="1"/>
                                </LinearGradientBrush>
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Panel.ZIndex" Value="1"/>
                        <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="Bd" Value="#FFF9F9F9"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <MultiTrigger>
                        <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Condition Property="IsSelected" Value="False"/>
                            <Condition Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True"/>
                        </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="Bd" Value="#FF3C7FB1"/>
                    </MultiTrigger>
                    <Trigger Property="TabStripPlacement" Value="Bottom">
                        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" TargetName="Bd" Value="1,0,1,1"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="TabStripPlacement" Value="Left">
                        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" TargetName="Bd" Value="1,1,0,1"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="TabStripPlacement" Value="Right">
                        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" TargetName="Bd" Value="0,1,1,1"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <MultiTrigger>
                        <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Condition Property="IsSelected" Value="True"/>
                            <Condition Property="TabStripPlacement" Value="Top"/>
                        </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="-2,-2,-2,-1"/>
                        <Setter Property="Margin" TargetName="Content" Value="0,0,0,1"/>
                    </MultiTrigger>
                    <MultiTrigger>
                        <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Condition Property="IsSelected" Value="True"/>
                            <Condition Property="TabStripPlacement" Value="Bottom"/>
                        </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="-2,-1,-2,-2"/>
                        <Setter Property="Margin" TargetName="Content" Value="0,1,0,0"/>
                    </MultiTrigger>
                    <MultiTrigger>
                        <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Condition Property="IsSelected" Value="True"/>
                            <Condition Property="TabStripPlacement" Value="Left"/>
                        </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="-2,-2,-1,-2"/>
                        <Setter Property="Margin" TargetName="Content" Value="0,0,1,0"/>
                    </MultiTrigger>
                    <MultiTrigger>
                        <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Condition Property="IsSelected" Value="True"/>
                            <Condition Property="TabStripPlacement" Value="Right"/>
                        </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="-1,-2,-2,-2"/>
                        <Setter Property="Margin" TargetName="Content" Value="1,0,0,0"/>
                    </MultiTrigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                        <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="Bd" Value="#FFF4F4F4"/>
                        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="Bd" Value="#FFC9C7BA"/>
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.GrayTextBrushKey}}"/>
                    </Trigger>

                    <!--You need this trigger to handle IsPressed changes-->
                    <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="Bd" Value="Red"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Comment: Beware: this does not imitate a button's behavior to get into pressed state again when the mouse leaves and enters again while the mouse button is pressed. So the tab item will not behave like a button.

Answer (score 0):

```
 You can also try this

<Grid>
    <TabControl Margin="10" BorderThickness="0" Background="LightGray">
        <TabControl.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="TabItem">
                <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="TabItem">
                            <Grid Name="Panel">
                                <ContentPresenter x:Name="ContentSite"
                                    VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                    HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                    ContentSource="Header"
                                    Margin="10,2"/>
                            </Grid>
                            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                                    <Setter TargetName="Panel" Property="Background" Value="LightSkyBlue" />
                                </Trigger>
                                <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="False">
                                    <Setter TargetName="Panel" Property="Background" Value="White" />
                                </Trigger>
                            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>
        </TabControl.Resources>
        <TabItem Header="General">
            <Label Content="Content goes here..." />
        </TabItem>
        <TabItem Header="Security" />
        <TabItem Header="Details" />
    </TabControl>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Thans for the code snippet. This is for selected tab not for pressed. I want to change the backgroumd only for that time untill user has pressed left mouse button. once mouse is release it goes back to normal.